# Global Variable per IE tab Asp Classic

Tags: internet-explorer, session, asp-classic

Someone has a opinion or alredy tried to use a global variable per IE tab in Asp Classic.
I have to pass a value between several pages and I can't to use Sessions to do it, because I can't rewrite the values in the Session, I need some like a Session per tab.

Comment: This is not possible in ASP alone. You can do this with JavaScript on the client, not in the server.

Each tab/window represents a page access on the same session at the server level.

Maybe, if you explain what you want to do we could help in findind a solution.

Comment: 1 - I have a screen pop-up that call my url pass a ID by query string.
2 - The page get this one by query string and it need to pass this one to the others pages.
I need to use this ID between pages in a browser tab scope. But I can't use Sessions. Session will rewrite the value as soon as a new tab open by my screen pop-up. Tks @rcdmk !

Comment: Sorry to inform you that the only way around this is to redirect the user with the querystring appended to the URL and use forms with a hidden field or links with the querystring to pass this value with user interaction.

Comment: Why not store the value in a hidden field and make sure you navigate by POST or GET?

Comment: Because I have too much pages in my sistem, if I use this approach, I'll have to change much pages. Because of this, I need a variable per tab. tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in ASP alone. Since ASP runs in the server, it doesn't "know" about tabs or windows.

Each tab/window represents a page access on the same session at the server level.

To overcome this you can pass along the variable through recirects, links and include it in hidden fields of forms the user interacts with.

Comment: I found a workround, but I don't know, if this approach can really solve this problem. I'm use the window.name (javascript  variable) to use a global variable por tab. What do you think about it ?

Comment: I think you have many possibilities in JavaScript. If you are using AJAX, you can have an unique identifier like this and send it to your ASP backend to identify each tab.

Comment: Another way is to generate a random identifier for each page access and generate a hidden field or append this to the link URLs.